# Alias text in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, alias

I want to alias the text in HTML or CSS. Or, I am sure it can be done with javascript (and maybe vbscript or tcl).

[In a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538570/is-it-possible-to-disable-font-smoothing-in-css) a user posted these codes:

```
font-smooth: auto | never | always |  | length | initial | inherit
-webkit-font-smoothing : none | subpixel-antialiased | antialiased
```

However, `font-smooth: never;` and `-webkit-font-smoothing : none;` did not do the job and I suspect there may [sadly] be no option to alias text.

*P.S: Aliased text: text rendered as either black or white pixels*:

[image]

Comment: i am also facing same issues !! in a similar ques.. http://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/

Comment: You're correct that there is no way to do this in CSS. Font rendering is handled almost entirely by the operating system.

Comment: I understand that you want to achieve some visual effect(?) then why you don't use font looking like this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force a font to be aliased at the extent you have in your example. That's not aliased as much as a blown-up pixel font.

Fonts that you use in a web page are *not* bitmap fonts. They are vector fonts. Meaning there are no pixels to alias. *

Your best bet is to find a standard font that is drawn to look like bitmaps and simply use that...with or without font smoothing.

* back in the day fonts *did* have a set of bitmaps that went along with the vector data. This was called [hinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting). However, these, too, were not designed to be blown up beyond their 1 image to 1 screen pixel ratio.

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to do this via css for many reasons:

1.- you are fighting, first and foremost, against browsers and OS settings. Cleartype, DirectWrite, etc. are not always set via the browser's settings but rather through the OS.

2.- css properties for antialiasing are not consistent among all primary browsers.

3.- font-smoothing is no longer existent if I recall correctly.

So, having said that, why don't you look for a font that has the style you want, such as :

http://www.fontspace.com/kreative-korporation/chixa

G

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome and Safari on OSX, you can use:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: none
```

I don't think this will work on any other operating systems, or in Firefox.

If you need something that will work on a broader range of browsers, try using a font that's created to look pixelated, like http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Press+Start+2P