# Can I alias a font in CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, alias

[The difference between anti-aliasing and aliasing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M9hu.gif)

Is there any way I can recreate this effect in CSS? You might be asking, "why would I want to do that to a font?" Well, I'm designing a retro-graphics web game (link [here](http://memeclicker.github.io)) and I feel the anti-aliasing would kill the feel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable font smoothing in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538570/is-it-possible-to-disable-font-smoothing-in-css)

Comment: You might choose to use a custom font. http://www.fontspace.com/category/1980s and more to find from your search engine :)